# "duplicate .fnstart directive" error in crti.s when cross compile glibc

Tags: arm, cross-compiling, glibc

I'm trying to cross compile glibc 2.10.1 with arm-none-linux-gnueabi-gcc 4.4.1.

Process went well until it assemble build_dir/csu/crti.S, gcc reports "duplicate .fnstart directive" error.

initfini.s and crti.s were generated, but I don't know if they were valid or not.

Makefile intend to split initfini.s into crti.s and crtn.s, so the .fnstart .fnend pairs in initfini.s were split into crti.s and crtn.s, and then they were not matched, resulting in gcc complaint of duplicate .fnstart directive.

So how can I compile crti.o and crtn.o out with this version 4.4.1 gcc? Any advice is appreciated.

initfini.s

```
    .arch armv5te
    .fpu softvfp
    .eabi_attribute 20, 1
    .eabi_attribute 21, 1
    .eabi_attribute 23, 3
    .eabi_attribute 24, 1
    .eabi_attribute 25, 1
    .eabi_attribute 26, 2
    .eabi_attribute 30, 2
    .eabi_attribute 18, 4
    .file   "initfini.c"
#APP
    
#include "defs.h"
    
/*@HEADER_ENDS*/
    
/*@TESTS_BEGIN*/
    .text
    .align  2
    .global dummy
    .type   dummy, %function
dummy:
    .fnstart
.LFB8:
    @ args = 0, pretend = 0, frame = 0
    @ frame_needed = 0, uses_anonymous_args = 0
    cmp r0, #0
    stmfd   sp!, {r3, lr}
    .save {r3, lr}
.LCFI0:
    ldmeqfd sp!, {r3, pc}
    blx r0
    ldmfd   sp!, {r3, pc}
.LFE8:
    .fnend
#APP
    
/*@TESTS_END*/
    
/*@_init_PROLOG_BEGINS*/
    .align  2
    .type   call_gmon_start, %function
call_gmon_start:
    .fnstart
.LFB9:
    @ args = 0, pretend = 0, frame = 0
    @ frame_needed = 0, uses_anonymous_args = 0
    @ link register save eliminated.
    ldr r3, .L8
    ldr r0, .L8+4
.LPIC0:
    add r3, pc, r3
    ldr r2, [r3, r0]
    cmp r2, #0
    bxeq    lr
    b   __gmon_start__(PLT)
.L9:
    .align  2
.L8:
    .word   _GLOBAL_OFFSET_TABLE_-(.LPIC0+8)
    .word   __gmon_start__(GOT)
.LFE9:
    .fnend
#APP
    .section .init
    .section    .init,"ax",%progbits
    .align  2
    .global _init
    .type   _init, %function
_init:
    .fnstart
.LFB10:
    @ args = 0, pretend = 0, frame = 0
    @ frame_needed = 0, uses_anonymous_args = 0
    stmfd   sp!, {r3, lr}
    .save {r3, lr}
.LCFI1:
    bl  call_gmon_start(PLT)
#APP
@ 96 "../sysdeps/generic/initfini.c" 1
    ALIGN
@ 0 "" 2
@ 97 "../sysdeps/generic/initfini.c" 1
    END_INIT
@ 0 "" 2
@ 99 "../sysdeps/generic/initfini.c" 1
    
/*@_init_PROLOG_ENDS*/
@ 0 "" 2
@ 100 "../sysdeps/generic/initfini.c" 1
    
/*@_init_EPILOG_BEGINS*/
@ 0 "" 2
@ 101 "../sysdeps/generic/initfini.c" 1
    .section .init
@ 0 "" 2
    ldmfd   sp!, {r3, pc}
.LFE10:
    .fnend
#APP
    END_INIT
    
/*@_init_EPILOG_ENDS*/
    
/*@_fini_PROLOG_BEGINS*/
    .section .fini
    .section    .fini,"ax",%progbits
    .align  2
    .global _fini
    .type   _fini, %function
_fini:
    .fnstart
.LFB11:
    @ args = 0, pretend = 0, frame = 0
    @ frame_needed = 0, uses_anonymous_args = 0
    stmfd   sp!, {r3, lr}
    .save {r3, lr}
.LCFI2:
#APP
@ 116 "../sysdeps/generic/initfini.c" 1
    ALIGN
@ 0 "" 2
@ 117 "../sysdeps/generic/initfini.c" 1
    END_FINI
@ 0 "" 2
@ 118 "../sysdeps/generic/initfini.c" 1
    
/*@_fini_PROLOG_ENDS*/
@ 0 "" 2
    bl  i_am_not_a_leaf(PLT)
#APP
@ 129 "../sysdeps/generic/initfini.c" 1
    
/*@_fini_EPILOG_BEGINS*/
@ 0 "" 2
@ 130 "../sysdeps/generic/initfini.c" 1
    .section .fini
@ 0 "" 2
    ldmfd   sp!, {r3, pc}
.LFE11:
    .fnend
#APP
    END_FINI
    
/*@_fini_EPILOG_ENDS*/
    
/*@TRAILER_BEGINS*/
    .weak   __gmon_start__
    .weak   __gmon_start__
    .weak   __gmon_start__
    .weak   __gmon_start__
    .weak   __gmon_start__
    .ident  "GCC: (Sourcery G++ Lite 2009q3-67) 4.4.1"
    .section    .note.GNU-stack,"",%progbits
```

crti.s

```
    .arch armv5te
    .fpu softvfp
    .eabi_attribute 20, 1
    .eabi_attribute 21, 1
    .eabi_attribute 23, 3
    .eabi_attribute 24, 1
    .eabi_attribute 25, 1
    .eabi_attribute 26, 2
    .eabi_attribute 30, 2
    .eabi_attribute 18, 4
    .file   "initfini.c"
#APP
    
#include "defs.h"
    
/*@HEADER_ENDS*/
/*@_init_PROLOG_BEGINS*/
    .align  2
    .type   call_gmon_start, %function
call_gmon_start:
    .fnstart
.LFB9:
    @ args = 0, pretend = 0, frame = 0
    @ frame_needed = 0, uses_anonymous_args = 0
    @ link register save eliminated.
    ldr r3, .L8
    ldr r0, .L8+4
.LPIC0:
    add r3, pc, r3
    ldr r2, [r3, r0]
    cmp r2, #0
    bxeq    lr
    b   __gmon_start__(PLT)
.L9:
    .align  2
.L8:
    .word   _GLOBAL_OFFSET_TABLE_-(.LPIC0+8)
    .word   __gmon_start__(GOT)
.LFE9:
    .fnend
#APP
    .section .init
    .section    .init,"ax",%progbits
    .align  2
    .global _init
    .type   _init, %function
_init:
    .fnstart
.LFB10:
    @ args = 0, pretend = 0, frame = 0
    @ frame_needed = 0, uses_anonymous_args = 0
    stmfd   sp!, {r3, lr}
    .save {r3, lr}
.LCFI1:
    bl  call_gmon_start(PLT)
#APP
@ 96 "../sysdeps/generic/initfini.c" 1
    ALIGN
@ 0 "" 2
@ 97 "../sysdeps/generic/initfini.c" 1
    END_INIT
@ 0 "" 2
@ 99 "../sysdeps/generic/initfini.c" 1
    
/*@_init_PROLOG_ENDS*/
/*@_fini_PROLOG_BEGINS*/
    .section .fini
    .section    .fini,"ax",%progbits
    .align  2
    .global _fini
    .type   _fini, %function
_fini:
    .fnstart
.LFB11:
    @ args = 0, pretend = 0, frame = 0
    @ frame_needed = 0, uses_anonymous_args = 0
    stmfd   sp!, {r3, lr}
    .save {r3, lr}
.LCFI2:
#APP
@ 116 "../sysdeps/generic/initfini.c" 1
    ALIGN
@ 0 "" 2
@ 117 "../sysdeps/generic/initfini.c" 1
    END_FINI
@ 0 "" 2
@ 118 "../sysdeps/generic/initfini.c" 1
    
/*@_fini_PROLOG_ENDS*/
/*@TRAILER_BEGINS*/
    .weak   __gmon_start__
    .weak   __gmon_start__
    .weak   __gmon_start__
    .weak   __gmon_start__
    .weak   __gmon_start__
    .ident  "GCC: (Sourcery G++ Lite 2009q3-67) 4.4.1"
    .section    .note.GNU-stack,"",%progbits
```

gcc version

```
arm-none-linux-gnueabi-gcc (Sourcery G++ Lite 2009q3-67) 4.4.1
Copyright (C) 2009 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
```

compile command

```
arm-none-linux-gnueabi-gcc ../ports/sysdeps/arm/initfini.c -c -std=gnu99 -fgnu89-inline -O2 -Wall -Winline -Wwrite-strings -fmerge-all-constants -g -Wstrict-prototypes    -g0 -fPIC -fno-inline-functions -fno-toplevel-reorder -fno-section-anchors  -I../include -I/home/user/Downloads/glibc-2.10.1/build/csu -I/home/user/Downloads/glibc-2.10.1/build -I../ports/sysdeps/arm/elf -I../ports/sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/arm/eabi/nptl -I../ports/sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/arm/eabi -I../ports/sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/arm/nptl -I../ports/sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/arm -I../nptl/sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux -I../nptl/sysdeps/pthread -I../sysdeps/pthread -I../ports/sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux -I../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux -I../sysdeps/gnu -I../sysdeps/unix/common -I../sysdeps/unix/mman -I../sysdeps/unix/inet -I../nptl/sysdeps/unix/sysv -I../ports/sysdeps/unix/sysv -I../sysdeps/unix/sysv -I../ports/sysdeps/unix/arm -I../nptl/sysdeps/unix -I../ports/sysdeps/unix -I../sysdeps/unix -I../sysdeps/posix -I../ports/sysdeps/arm/eabi -I../ports/sysdeps/arm/fpu -I../ports/sysdeps/arm/nptl -I../ports/sysdeps/arm -I../sysdeps/wordsize-32 -I../sysdeps/ieee754/flt-32 -I../sysdeps/ieee754/dbl-64 -I../sysdeps/ieee754 -I../sysdeps/generic/elf -I../sysdeps/generic -I../nptl -I../ports  -I.. -I../libio -I.  -D_LIBC_REENTRANT -include ../include/libc-symbols.h       -DHAVE_INITFINI -S -g0 -fPIC -fno-inline-functions -fno-toplevel-reorder -fno-section-anchors -finhibit-size-directive -fno-exceptions -o /home/user/Downloads/glibc-2.10.1/build/csu/initfini.s
arm-none-linux-gnueabi-gcc /home/user/Downloads/glibc-2.10.1/build/csu/crti.S -c  -I../include -I/home/user/Downloads/glibc-2.10.1/build/csu -I/home/user/Downloads/glibc-2.10.1/build -I../ports/sysdeps/arm/elf -I../ports/sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/arm/eabi/nptl -I../ports/sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/arm/eabi -I../ports/sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/arm/nptl -I../ports/sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/arm -I../nptl/sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux -I../nptl/sysdeps/pthread -I../sysdeps/pthread -I../ports/sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux -I../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux -I../sysdeps/gnu -I../sysdeps/unix/common -I../sysdeps/unix/mman -I../sysdeps/unix/inet -I../nptl/sysdeps/unix/sysv -I../ports/sysdeps/unix/sysv -I../sysdeps/unix/sysv -I../ports/sysdeps/unix/arm -I../nptl/sysdeps/unix -I../ports/sysdeps/unix -I../sysdeps/unix -I../sysdeps/posix -I../ports/sysdeps/arm/eabi -I../ports/sysdeps/arm/fpu -I../ports/sysdeps/arm/nptl -I../ports/sysdeps/arm -I../sysdeps/wordsize-32 -I../sysdeps/ieee754/flt-32 -I../sysdeps/ieee754/dbl-64 -I../sysdeps/ieee754 -I../sysdeps/generic/elf -I../sysdeps/generic -I../nptl -I../ports  -I.. -I../libio -I.  -D_LIBC_REENTRANT -include ../include/libc-symbols.h       -DHAVE_INITFINI -DASSEMBLER  -I/home/user/Downloads/glibc-2.10.1/build/csu/.  -Wa,--noexecstack   -g0  -o /home/user/Downloads/glibc-2.10.1/build/csu/crti.o
```

Answer (score 0):

Both `.fnstart` and `.fnend` are LLVM directives marking the start and end position of a function.

You should replace them with `.func` and `.endfunc` respectively for GCC.